# Uncaught TypeError: core_1.style is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I transformed my code from Angular 4 to Angular 7 and compiled it successfully. 
But when I try to run it, in the console of the broser it gives the following errors.

[image: Please see this image]

```
Uncaught TypeError: core_1.style is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (ng2-dropdown.bundle.js:435)
at __webpack_require__ (ng2-dropdown.bundle.js:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (ng2-dropdown.bundle.js:121)
at __webpack_require__ (ng2-dropdown.bundle.js:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (ng2-dropdown.bundle.js:65)
at __webpack_require__ (ng2-dropdown.bundle.js:30)
at ng2-dropdown.bundle.js:50
at ng2-dropdown.bundle.js:53
at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (ng2-dropdown.bundle.js:3)
at Object../node_modules/ng2-tag-input/node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/dist/ng2-dropdown.bundle.js (ng2-dropdown.bundle.js:10)
```

Can someone point me out why I am getting this errors? I am very new to Angular. Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is actually with old version of `ng2-material-dropdown` where they're using the `style` function imported from`@angular/core` (https://v4.angular.io/api/core/style) which was deprecated in Angular 4 and moved to `@angular/animations` (https://angular.io/api/animations/style)

In 0.9.0 version ng2-material-dropdown library [added support](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ng2-material-dropdown/commit/6d13da6474f751065640e3930839415986cc048c#diff-98e2af26cfa1d5b82372572e1e80e44d) for Angular version 5 & 6  so I would suggest you update that library as well. At this moment there is 0.10.1 version available.

Comment: In my package.jason `ng2-material-dropdown` haven't been used! Insted `ng2-dropdown` is used! When I reloaded the page error was changed as above!  Same error, insted of `vendor` it is now 'ng2-dropdown'.

Comment: ng2-tag-input uses it internally. Try updating it

Comment: try `npm ls ng2-material-dropdown`. Also maybe you need to remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and run `npm i` again

Comment: it fix the error from the style . but the same error comes under `Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function` , are these errors are linked or is this because of another reason?

Comment: I don't know exactly what `__webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function` means without looking at reproducible example

Comment: its the same error insted of `Uncaught TypeError: core_1.style is not a function` now it is `Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function`

Comment: Can you share some repository on github with minimal reproduction?

Answer (score 0):

If all the solutions here don't solve your problem, you could try to remove the node_modules folder, and run `npm install` or `yarn` to reinstall all the dependencies, that's also mine solution.